# Google Chrome Extension to calculate source document hash

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wonder is it possible to calculate the hash of the opened document? Or even calculate hash of just loaded document, before JS got launched on the page?

Comment: Not in Chrome, no, because it doesn't expose the original server response. Well, technically you can attach to the tab via `chrome.debugger` API and get that response using RDP commands, but there'll be an annoying warning displayed to the user at the top of the tab. P.S. note that in a browser JavaScript runs while the page is parsed and loaded, there's no separation.

Comment: @wOxxOm will check if debugger can be used for some domains only.

Comment: The command is [Network.getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody), afaik.